# How to add a "publish" link to the quick actions

Tags: posts, filters, actions, publish, quick-edit

I'm trying to add a "Publish" link by the quick actions:

[image]

but I'm not exactly sure of how implement it.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions', function ( $actions )
{
    global $post;

    // If the post hasn't been published yet
    if ( get_post_status($post) != 'publish' )
    {
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce('quick-publish-action');

        $link = get_admin_url('path to where') . "?id={$post->id}&amp;_wpnonce=$nonce";

        $actions['publish'] = "<a href=\"$link\">Publish</a>";
    }

    return $actions;
});
```

As you can see, I don't know where to link to in `get_admin_url`. I think I should be using [`wp_publish_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post), but I don't know where to put that code, and how to link to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without doing Ajax (like in Quick Edit), the `admin_url` should be the very `edit.php` page.

Note that:

- the filter `post_row_actions` takes two arguments, the second one being `$post`, so the global is not necessary.
- instead of using `id` as query argument, it's best practice to use custom names, in this case `update_id`.
- I didn't know the function `get_admin_url` and normally use [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) for this.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', function ( $actions, $post )
{
    if ( get_post_status( $post ) != 'publish' )
    {
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'quick-publish-action' ); 
        $link = admin_url( "edit.php?update_id={$post->ID}&_wpnonce=$nonce" );
        $actions['publish'] = "<a href='$link'>Publish</a>";
    }   
    return $actions;
},
10, 2 );
```

Then, we need to hook in a very early action, `load-edit.php`, and perform a [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) if the nonce and `update_id` are ok:

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
    $nonce = isset( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] ) ? $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] : null;
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'quick-publish-action' ) && isset( $_REQUEST['update_id'] ) )
    {
        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $_REQUEST['update_id'];
        $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Passing a second argument into the filter function gives me an error that it's missing argument two (running WP 3.5.1 on PHP 5.3).

Comment: Also, any reason you're not simply using [`wp_publish_post($_REQUEST['update_id'])`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post)? That's 1 line of code instead of 4.

Comment: Have you seen `priority, arguments` / `10, 2` in `add_filter('hook',function(){}, 10, 2)`? Donnow, never used `wp_publish_post`, what do your tests reveal?