# Modify action buttons for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have created a custom post type called "form-enquiry". I'm trying to change the actions that appear when the admin hovers over the posts on the `edit.php` page. See screenshot below

[image]

I managed to find the array which was holding the settings and add my own custom one called "reply" into the array. However, I can't work out how to get post id for the link.

See below for the code I have so far. Is it possible to get the id for the post and insert it into the link to get something like `post.php?post=95&action=reply` when the user clicks on the custom button.

```
  function remove_quick_edit($actions)
  {
    if($_GET['post_type'] == 'form-enquiry')
    {
      unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }

    $actions['reply'] = '<a href="#">Reply</a>';
    //return $actions;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($actions); echo '</pre>';
  }
  add_filter('post_row_actions', 'remove_quick_edit', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/, the second argument for the `post_row_actions` filter is a post object, so you should be able to do :

```
 function remove_quick_edit($actions, $post)
  {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $post_type = $post->post_type;
    if($_GET['post_type'] == 'form-enquiry')
    {
      unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }

    $actions['reply'] = '<a href="#">Reply</a>';
    //return $actions;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($actions); echo '</pre>';
  }
  add_filter('post_row_actions', 'remove_quick_edit', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is any way to add a custom action to these? I see when I click on the Edit button I get this link `?post=95&action=edit` Is it possible to create a link with `&action=reply`? I tried manually putting this in but WordPress throws this error "Are you sure you want to do this?"

Comment: You may need a nonce, this answer here provides some information on that http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99211/how-to-add-a-publish-link-to-the-quick-actions#answer-99230